# How to install Windows updates automatically during the Windows installation?

Tags: installation, windows-11, windows-update, automation, unattended

During the Windows 11 installation, there is a step called «Installing updates»:

[image]

Is it possible to provide a set of already downloaded KBs `*.msu`, which will be installed automatically during the Windows installation? If yes, where exactly should I copy these `*.msu`?

P.S. I remember that previously it used to be possible to copy the Windows Update installers into some folder inside of the Windows installation USB and then these updates would be installed automatically during the Windows installation, but I forgot the name of such folder.

Comment: Yes, you can, you have to update the windows image with DiSM. Thats how [UUPDump](https://uupdump.net/) works. You can download and update a Windows image, create a ISO, by literally applying the update to the windows image. What point in the process of updating a Windows image are you stuck on?

Comment: @Ramhound, thx. I'm aware about ability to slipstream the updates into the ISO with `DISM` or other tools. I thought it's possible to copy the `.msu` into some folder inside of installation USB without additional `DISM` manipulations. I'm not stuck on some point, I'm observing how Windows Update deals with drivers update and I just don't rely on it, I'm skeptical that it's smart enough to download updates in the most optimal order: the latest cumulative firstly, then the rest of available updates.

Comment: That method is no longer exists.We now have DISM a tool that can be used to modify and build Windows images. Having to resort to just updates being applied is a discontinued method.Only the latest cumulative update is required,it contains the fixes, included in previous cumulative updates.Microsoft changed how they released updates more than a decade ago.It’s no longer required to install hundreds of updates like it was on Windows 7, shortly before Windows 7 reached end of life, even Windows 7 was updated with cumulative updates instead of sequential updates which required the previous update